# Cannot upload the Image to server java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

I'm trying to upload some Image file to my database. When I run my code It produces the error `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:`. But the same code works well in another form.

My code is :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String uname = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("uname");
    //set content type
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    DiskFileItemFactory  fileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory ();

     fileItemFactory.setSizeThreshold(1*1024*1024); //1 MB

    ServletFileUpload uploadHandler = new ServletFileUpload(fileItemFactory);
    try {
            if (! ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            System.out.println("sorry. No file uploaded");
            return;
        }

        // parse request
        List<?> items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);  //getting error
        System.out.println(items.size());
         // get uploaded file
        FileItem file = (FileItem) items.get(0);

                Connection con=prepareConnection();
                con.setAutoCommit(false);

                 //Part photo=request.getPart("photo");
                BufferedImage originalImage=ImageIO.read(file.getInputStream());
                int type = originalImage.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : originalImage.getType();
                BufferedImage resizeImageJpg = resizeImage(originalImage, type);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(resizeImageJpg, "png", baos);
                baos.flush();
                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

                StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(1024);
                sb.append("insert into ").append(uname).append("PROFILEPICTURE values(?,?)");
                String query = sb.toString();
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                ps.setInt(1, 1);
                ps.setBinaryStream(2, is);

                int i=ps.executeUpdate();
                con.commit();
                con.close();

                if(i==1)
                {
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/sp/profile");
                if(dispatcher != null) {
                    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
                }
                }
                else
                {
                    out.println("Error ocuured");
                }
            out.close();

        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

console output :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at skypark.AddProfilePict.doPost(AddProfilePict.java:79)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And my form is:

```html
<form id="form" method="post" action="AddProfilePict" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" style="width: 450px; border:0px; background:none; margin-top:5px; width:245px;" value="">
<input class="upld" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is causing the error?

Comment: `items` is an empty list, so you can't access to `items.get(0);`. How are you submitting the file to the server? Try to not use an ajax call.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza  I'm not making ajax call. I'm submitting the data in normal way...

Comment: Can you please post a complete sample in order to replicate the problem?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza I updated the question..

Comment: Again, are you sure you're not submitting the form using an ajax request? Based on the comment *//PrintWriter to send the JSON response back*

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza I tried first to submit the form using ajax and I found that it is not possible to upload the file using ajax. Because of that the comment having there. Now I'm not uploading the file using ajax....

Comment: Ok, is the file that you're trying to submit bigger than 1 MB? If not, then can you just create a new page with `<form>` and `<input type="file">` and a `<input type="submit>"` to reproduce the problem and see if it's happening? That should give you new results for the problem.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza no it's only 25KB

Comment: Please learn how to identify the cause of the problem. Your problem is not caused by the line `List<?> items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);`. Your problem is caused by the line `FileItem file = (FileItem) items.get(0);`. The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is just your own fault because you invoked `get(0)` on an empty list. You should not concentrate on fixing that exception (which can be just done by e.g. `if (!items.isEmpty())` check beforehand). You should concentrate on why that list is empty. In such question, the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is **completely irrelevant**.

Comment: @james do you still have problem with this?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza No, But one thing is I didn't got the problem what is, I just changed my complete form, and the problem automatically resolved... Thank you for your reply....

Comment: How did you *changed your complete form*? Maybe there was anything that you haven't post here that caused the problem and you deleted when changing the form.

Comment: What I changed is `<form id="form1" method="post" action="AddProfilePict" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" accept="image/*" name="photo"><input type="submit" value="Upload Photo"></form>` In this I didn't added style for `input` `file`. Other than that no change have in this...

Answer (score 0):

`items` should indeed be empty. You should first check it's length and then try to fetch the items using

```
if(! items.isEmpty()) {
    FileItem file = (FileItem) items.get(0); 
}
```

or

```
if(items.size() > 0) {
    FileItem file = (FileItem) items.get(0); 
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why `List<?> items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);` returning `0`  when i print the `items`

Comment: @james Ensure the file being upload does meet the size requirement.